# How to calculate the approximate size range of an image based on resolution before capturing image

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, image-size, android-camerax

I'm trying to implement a resolution based Image capture
And my device supports the below resolution

```
  4640x3472 ,4624x3472 ,4624x2600 ,4624x2136 ,3840x2160 ,3472x3472 ,2560x1920 ,
  1920x1440 ,2340x1080 ,1920x1080 ,1440x1080 ,1080x1080 ,1440x720 ,1280x720 ,
  960x720 ,720x480 ,640x480 ,352x288 ,320x240 ,176x144 ,9248x6936
```

Now, I also need to show an approximate size of an image if captured like

```
640x480 (~200-500kb)
1920x1440 (~1.5-3Mb)
 ...
```

With some research I came up with this blog
[how to calculate file size of digital-image](https://4nsi.com/faq/how-do-i-calculate-the-file-size-for-a-digital-image)

```
1 Byte = 8 Bit 1 Kilobyte = 1,024 Bytes 1 Megabyte = 1,048,576 Bytes 1 Gigabyte = 1,073,741,824

2,949,120 X 16 bit = 47185920 ÷ 8bits = 5,898,240 Bytes 5,760 Kilobytes ÷ 1024 = 5.625 Megabytes)
```

But, My camera taking images with varying sizes and it is not matching to these numbers.

How, to calculate the approximate size range of an image based on resolution before capturing image ?

Comment: Why do you need the exact size, or why wouldn't an approximate size (which you seem to already have) not be sufficient here?

Comment: from my limited understanding of images.  The memory (size) of an image is not bound to the resolution directly but is bound to what the pixels contain.  Since images may use compression mechanisms to reduce the size by creating pointers of where an image has similar colored pixels

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My requirement is such i need to reduce image size to user specified number. So, I'm giving him an option to choose the resolution which if taken whose size falls in between min and max size showed. So, i need a way to calculate min and max size based on these resolution.

Comment: @objectObject That's great information. Can you give me some links so that I will read through that.